# Why can I format my dates by regional settings in Chrome but not Firefox in my Javascript application using toLocaleDateString()?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, date-formatting, regional-settings

We are developing an AngularJS application in which we would like dates formatted by the user's region. I am implementing this in the following way:

```
row.StartLocal = new Date(start).toLocaleDateString();
row.EndLocal = new Date(end).toLocaleDateString();
```

```
...
<td>
    <span class="baseline-item-name">{{ b.StartLocal }} - {{ b.EndLocal }}</span>
</td>
...
```

And I get this in the UI:

[image]

This is correct for 'en-US' the format of which is MM/DD/YYYY.

Then I switch my region (using Windows 10) to 'en-UK':

[image]

And it has no effect in the UI. At least in Chrome. In Firefox, on the other hand, I see this:

[image]

which is correct for 'en-UK' the format of which is DD/MM/YYYY.

So my question is: why does toLocaleDateString() work in Firefox but not in Chrome? Or in other words, is there a way to get Chrome to respond to the regional settings of the user's OS the way Firefox does, or is that just not possible with Chrome?

Comment: You might have to [change Chrome settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221494/how-to-change-the-locale-in-chrome-browser) not the OS settings for this

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69568454/what-where-is-the-locale-stored-in-chrome-browser